# How to load Google sheets data to Google Cloud MySQL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

I have a dataset in Google sheets which frequently gets updated. I would like to push updates to google cloud MySQL.

Comment: As an alternative; if you choose BigQuery it is straight forward what you'd like to achieve, doesn't requires coding. You can check this [blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-crunch-your-business-data-from-sheets-in-bigquery) for connecting Google Sheets with BigQuery which also will receive the Sheet updates automatically.

Answer (score 0):

see Google App Script [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) and [Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

... while one can connect with App Script through [JDBC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc).

Comment: Where can I find the exact code for that? Could you please help me with that. I'm new to this.

Comment: @BalajiKatakam can only tell how it basically works, showing which classes to use; because ordinary I'm offering App Script scripting as a service. and it's impossible to provide any code - while neither knowing the spreadsheet nor the database.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Skyvia for connecting Google Sheets and Google Cloud SQL MySQL without coding: https://skyvia.com/data-integration/integrate-google-sheets-google-cloud-sql-mysql. All I need is to specify the connections to Google Sheets and Google Cloud SQL MySQL and select data to replicate. Skyvia will copy the specified Google Sheets data to Google Cloud SQL MySQL and maintain this copy up-to-date automatically with incremental updates.

Comment: You are a little too impressed by the tool you recommend ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion ) and you provide too little information for making an acceptable answer. Describing **what** the advertised tool does is not enough, you need to demonstrate **how** it solves the specific problem described in the question at the top of this page. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143930/how-can-i-connect-to-heroku-postgres-from-a-google-spreadsheet/72613039#72613039